# Set AWS Cognito access token timeout manually

Tags: amazon-web-services, access-token, amazon-cognito

Is there anyway to change the access token timeout in AWS Cognito?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Amazon Cognito User Pools now enables customers to choose how long their access and refresh tokens should be valid. Access tokens can be configured to expire in as little as five minutes or as long as 24 hours. Refresh tokens can be configured to expire in as little as one hour or as long as ten years.

Reference:

1. [08/2020: Cognito Token Expiration](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/08/amazon-cognito-user-pools-supports-customization-of-token-expiration/)
2. [Using Tokens with User Pools - Amazon Cognito](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-with-identity-providers.html)